# find_if can not detect the vector is empty

Tags: c++, vector

I want to use `find_if` from `#include <algorithm>`, however the problem is it can not recognize that the vector is empty or not.

Assume the following snippet

```
typedef std::vector< std::pair<int , int > > myVector;
myVector aVector;
struct equal: std::unary_function< std::pair<int , int >,bool >
{
  equal(const int &aNum) : theNum(aNum) {}
  bool operator()(const std::pair<int , int > &arg) const { return arg.first == theNum; }
  const int &theNum;
};
...

void check_and_insert(int num) {
   myVector::iterator it = find_if( aVector.begin(), aVector.end(), equal(num));
   if (it == aVector.end())
     aVector.push_back( std::make_pair(num, 1) );
   else
     ++dit->second;
}
```

Assume `aVector` is empty. I see that result of `find_if` is not `aVector.end()` so it goes to `else` which is wrong. Is this the way that find_if work? It is strange but I can fix that by inserting the first element:

```
if (aVector.empty()) {
  aVector.push_back( std::make_pair(num, 1) );
  return;
}
// find_if...
```

Is this the only solution? Is there any better idea?

**UPDATE** 
As stated in the comments, the find_if works properly. The bug was that `aVector` was modified by a call by reference in another function. Thanks for all helps and sorry for disturbance

Comment: Are you completely sure about this?

Comment: You certainly should get the "end" iterator if the sequence is empty. Are you sure you're not? Is `aVector` the same vector as `aVecotr`?

Comment: If `aVector` is empty, then `aVector.begin()' should equal `aVector.last()` and `find_if` should return `aVector.last()`. So it should work as [advertised](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/). Are you sure the problem doesn't lie elsewhere?

Comment: `aVecotr or aVector`? you have two vectors which have similar name? and looks like std::map is a better option for you.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: yes that was atypo. I fixed it

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yes. The snippet is quite simple. You can test it by putting it in a main function

Comment: @mahmood see live sample:  http://ideone.com/Gd69QJ

Comment: If you're really getting the behaviour you describe, it must mean your memory has been corrupted somewhere and part of the object `aVector` clobbered, so that the values you get from `begin()` and/or `end()` are garbage.

Comment: Like [this](http://ideone.com/glv8mw)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is somewhere in your code, since by standard:

> Returns: The first iterator i in the range [first,last) for which the following corresponding condi-
>  tions hold: *i == value, pred(*i) != false, pred(*i) == false. **Returns last if no such iterator
> is found.**

Comment: Let me look at it again.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is too long for a comment, here is an example using the same functor as you use:

```
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

struct equal: std::unary_function< std::pair<int , int >,bool >
{
  equal(const int &aNum) : theNum(aNum) {}
  bool operator()(const std::pair<int , int > &arg) const 
  { 
    return arg.first == theNum; 
  }
  const int &theNum;
};

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
  typedef std::vector< std::pair<int , int > > myVector;
  myVector aVector;
  int num = 42;
  myVector::iterator it = find_if( aVector.begin(), aVector.end(), equal(num));
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  std::cout << (it==aVector.end()) << std::endl;
}
```

output

> true

This seems to disprove the premise of your question.

Comment: OK thanks. It seems that find_if is working correctly for you. Let me debug it more. It seems that multiple objects access `aVector`.

Comment: aa yes... `aVector` had been modified by a ((call by reference)) in another function... Was a silly question but finally I found the bug

Answer (score 0):

In this sample test code, the comparison with `vector::end()` seems to work fine (VS2010 SP1):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
   /*   
    v.push_back(11);
    v.push_back(22);
    v.push_back(33);
   */ 

    auto it = find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int x){ return (x % 2) == 1; } );    

    if (it != v.end())
        cout << *it;
    else
        cout << "Not found.";

    cout << endl;
}
```

Output:

> Not found.

---

**EDIT**

In the comment section you asked to test your code snippet. Actually your code snippet is not a compilable snippet, so I'd suggest in the future to provide a *compilable* code snippet if you want others to test it.

In any case, I tried to adjust your original code, e.g. using some convenient **C++11** features available in VS2010 SP1, like *lambdas* (instead of functors), or `auto`.

And this test code works:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

typedef vector<pair<int, int>> MyVector;

void CheckAndInsert(MyVector& aVector, int num) 
{
    auto it = find_if( 
        aVector.begin(), aVector.end(), 
        [=](const std::pair<int, int>& elem)
        {
            return elem.first == num;
        }
    );

    if (it == aVector.end())
    {
        cout << "*** EMPTY VECTOR*** (num == " << num << ")\n";

        aVector.push_back( make_pair(num, 1) );
    }
    else
    {
        ++(it->second);
    }
}

int main()
{
    MyVector aVector;

    CheckAndInsert(aVector, 1);
    CheckAndInsert(aVector, 1);
    CheckAndInsert(aVector, 2);
    CheckAndInsert(aVector, 3);
    CheckAndInsert(aVector, 4);
    CheckAndInsert(aVector, 3);

    for (auto it = aVector.begin(); it != aVector.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << "(" << (it->first) << ", " << (it->second) << ")\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> *** EMPTY VECTOR*** (num == 1)
> *** EMPTY VECTOR*** (num == 2)
> *** EMPTY VECTOR*** (num == 3)
> *** EMPTY VECTOR*** (num == 4)
> (1, 2)
> (2, 1)
> (3, 2)
> (4, 1)
> ```

As a side note, you may also consider using a `std::map<int, int>` instead of `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>`.

Comment: Can you test my snippet. I am also debugging with VS2010.

Comment: I've edited my answer to add a snippet more similar to your original code (but using convenient C++11 features).

Answer (score 0):

> Assume aVector is empty. I see that result of find_if is not aVector.end()

Here you have a contradiction. If you pass an `begin()`, `end()` on empty vector that's empty range and end() will get returned from `find_if` immediately.